# Chrome browser ignoring parental controls

Tags: google-chrome, parental-controls

I'm running MacOS 10.13.6 and it seems that the Chrome browser is ignoring the parental controls that I've set up for kids' accounts.  If I try to go to a particular website in Safari it blocks it.  However, that very same website is allowed in Chrome.  Is this expected behavior?  Is there something I can do to make Chrome follow the parental rules?

Comment: Editing [`/etc/hosts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) is an option for technical users

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behavior, parental control only apply to the applications provided by Apple. At the time we needed that, we just blocked access to other applications through Parental Control.

Comment: That's unfortunate. You would think that blocking things at the OS level would take precedence over the application level.

Comment: What’s interesting is that when I previously had it set to “allow only these websites” it would throw warnings when Word, etc, tried to access things outside that list, so I’m not sure I buy the idea that it’s only applications provided by Apple.

Answer (score 4):

There are parental controls built into Chrome. The concept of parental controls in the Chrome browser, revolves around supervised user profiles. If a child is forced to browse the web while signed in under one of these restricted profiles, their parent or guardian has the final say regarding where they go and what they do while online. Not only does Chrome allow you to block specific websites, but it also creates a report of which sites they actually did visit during their browsing session.

The step-by-step instructions for setting this up is given [here](https://www.lifewire.com/configure-parental-controls-in-google-chrome-4136777).

Comment: I'm puzzled that this is getting upvotes. As far as I can see, the ability to create supervised profiles was removed last year, and Family Link doesn't (yet?) support whitelisting/blocking websites, so this just doesn't seem to be possible in Chrome on macos at the moment. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3463947?hl=en . Would love to be corrected if this is still possible somehow, but the instructions at the supplied link don't work for me at least. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I have just removed chrome from my youngest boys laptop, as despite setting up parental controls on my router he can just bypass this. This should not be allowed just to make you use chrome solutions!